# Regex to get total price with space as separator

Tags: regex

I need to build a regex that would catch the total price, here some exemple:

```
Total:   145.01 $
Total:   1 145.01 $
Total:   00.01 $
Total:   12 345.01 $
```

It's need to get any price that follow 'Total: ', without the '$'.

That what I got so far : `(?<=\bTotal:\s*)(\d+.\d+)`

[RegExr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1jSh.png)

Comment: `\bTotal:\s*(\d(?:[\d\s.]*\d)?)` and get Group 1 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume:

- each string must begin `'Total:   '` (three spaces), the *prefix*;
- the last digit in the string must be followed by `' $'` (one space), the *suffix*, which is at the end of the string;
- the substring between the prefix and suffix must end `'.dd'`, where `'d'` presents any digit, the *cents*;
- the substring between the prefix and cents must match one of the following patterns, where `'d'` represents any digit: `'d'`, `'dd'`, `'ddd'`, `'d ddd'`, `'dd ddd'`, `'ddd ddd'`, `'d ddd ddd'`, `'dd ddd ddd'`, `'ddd ddd ddd'`, `'d ddd ddd ddd'` and so on;
- the return value is the substring between the prefix and suffix that meets the above requirements; and
- spaces will be removed from the substring returned as a separate step at the end.

We can use the following regular expression.

```
r = /\ATotal: {3}(\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*\.\d{2}) \$\z/
```

In Ruby (but if you don't know Ruby you'll get the idea):

```
arr = <<~_.split(/\n/)
Total:   145.01 $
Total:   1 145.01 $
Total:   00.01 $
Total:   12 345.01 $
Total:   1 241 345.01 $
Total:  1.00 $
Total:   1.00$
Total:   1.00 $x
My Total:  1.00 $
Total:   12 34.01 $
_
```

The following matches each string in the array `arr` and extracts the contents of capture group 1, which is shown on the right side of each line.

```
arr.each do |s|
  puts "\"#{(s + '"[r,1]').ljust(30)}: #{s[r,1] || 'no match'}"
end
```

```
"Total:   145.01 $"[r,1]       : 145.01
"Total:   1 145.01 $"[r,1]     : 1 145.01
"Total:   00.01 $"[r,1]        : 00.01
"Total:   12 345.01 $"[r,1]    : 12 345.01
"Total:   1 241 345.01 $"[r,1] : 1 241 345.01
"Total:  1.00 $"[r,1]          : no match
"Total:   1.00$"[r,1]          : no match
"Total:   1.00 $x"[r,1]        : no match
"My Total:  1.00 $"[r,1]       : no match
"Total:   12 34.01 $"[r,1]     : no match
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    \A             # match the beginning of the string 
    Total:\ {3}    # match 'Total:' followed by 3 digits
    (              # begin capture group 1
      \d{1,3}      # match 1, 2 or 3 digits
      (?:\ \d{3})  # match a space followed by 3 digits
      *            # perform the previous match zero or more times
      \.\d{2}      # match a period followed by 2 digits
    )              # end capture group 1
    \ \$           # match a space followed by a dollar sign 
    \z             # match end of string
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The regex can be seen in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/mndKEF/1).